# How do I Install Avidemux On Ubuntu 16.04.1?

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, lxde, avidemux

How do I install Avidemux On Ubuntu (LXDE)?

I have synaptic but I cannot find Avidemux in it. Should I add a repository to synaptic?

Comment: *Synaptic* is the preferred tool among Debian users, for UBUNTU community the most used and secure procedure is the terminal command-line `apt`  —  you can use `apt` command instead `apt-get`  to little-bit-more friendlly interaction... Or if you like only graphic interface, use the UBUNTU's central.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Very easy, run this in your terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rebuntu16/avidemux+unofficial
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install avidemux2.6-gtk avidemux2.6-qt4
```

Edit: The GTK+ packages are not supported any more since the interface does not work. Users should install the Qt4/Qt5 one instead.

Comment: version 2.6  Removed VOB to VobSub, VobSub to srt, and TS to srt subtitle tools
....Removed Subtitle video filters: VobSub, DVB Sub, ASS, Subtitler

Comment: got error:  `unable to locate package`

Comment: This PPA is not working anymore. By the way, do you know why avidemux package is not included in the official Ubuntu repository? (according to another answer here, it was included in repositories of older Ubuntu versions)

Answer (score 2):

avidemux disappeared from repositories after wily; I've resolved adding trusty (because is LTS) repos to my sources.list.

Obviously this installs 2.5.4 version, but the official one; if you prefer a newer one, the ppa method is better.

open a terminal and give:

```
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.bak
```

(or choose the filename you prefer) to backup your sources.list

then

```
sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list
```

or nano or gedit or ... the editor you like and add this line on the bottom:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted universe multiverse
```

finally update and install avidemux with

```
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install avidemux
```